# How to get AngularJS routing to work on IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer, angularjs, routes

I've got a clean AngularJS 1.2.8 app that I'm just starting.  Routing doesn't work on IE 8 but it does work in every other browser (including IE 9).  There are no errors in the console.  Angular just doesn't fire off the route.

Can someone point me in the right direction?  I've already had a look at [Angular's IE 8 doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie) and followed directions to no avail.

The HTML...

```
<!doctype html>
<html id="ng-app" data-ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Learning Content Portal</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container"> 
        <!-- placeholder for views -->
        <div data-ng-view></div>
    </div> <!-- /container --> 

    <script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/vendor/json3.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/vendor/angular/angular.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/vendor/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script> 

    <script src="js/app.js"></script> 

</body>
</html>
```

And the app.js...

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/searchCourses', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/searchCourses.html',
            controller: 'controller_searchCourses'
        })
        .when('/editCourse', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/editCourse.html',
            controller: 'editCourseController'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/searchCourses' });
});

app.controller('controller_searchCourses', function ($scope) {
    alert('test');
});
```

There's also a partial but I don't think that matters because it's never firing the alert (or loading the partial).

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        Course Count: {{courses.length}}
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="course in courses | orderBy:course.name">{{ course.name }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <br />

    <div>
        Name: <input type="text" data-ng-model="newCourse.name" /><br />
        Owner: <input type="text" data-ng-model="newCourse.owner" /><br />
        Code: <input type="text" data-ng-model="newCourse.code" /><br />
        Status: <input type="text" data-ng-model="newCourse.status" /><br />
        <br />
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="addCourse()">Add New Course</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No enabling of IE8 users!  ;)

Comment: Hah!  I wish.  Unfortunately, large corporate, slow to update.

Comment: I'm large corporate as well...and we just decided to no longer support them...they're at like 5% of traffic these days

Answer (score 4):

You didn't specify namespace in your html

`<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org">`

and the docs says it is required.

Comment: Ah...  good call.  Not sure how I missed that.  Tried it out but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I added this line to the config function...

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
```

...which didn't help.  But then I backed off to Angular 1.2.6 and it worked.  Something was introduced in 1.2.7 that breaks IE 8 modules/routing.

Answer (score 1):

There was a change introduced in Angular 1.2.7 that kind of broke routing on IE8. Here's the [commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/6c17d02bc4cc02f478775d62e1f9f77da9da82ad). It didn't really break it, it's just a security configuration issue. If you go to "Tools -> Internet options -> Advanced -> Security -> Enable native XMLHTTP support" and check it, then it works again.

Probably you can't just enable that option for all the users in your corporate network (that was my case), so there's 2 things you can do.

- First one is using Angular 1.2.11 or higher. They made [another change](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/ef210e5e119db4f5bfc9d2428b19f9b335c4f976) in that version that made routing in ie8 work again. Haven't checked other things though, but I suppose everything should work correctly on that version.
- If you have to stick with Angular 1.2.8 (or any version from 1.2.7 to 1.2.10), you can add this inside script tags to your index.html, after loading Angular, then it should work again:

```
(function() {
    window.XMLHttpRequest = window.XMLHttpRequest || (function() {
        return new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with how you write your routing, try this:

```
    app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/searchCourses', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/searchCourses.html',
            controller: 'controller_searchCourses'
        })
        .when('/editCourse', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/editCourse.html',
            controller: 'editCourseController'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/searchCourses' }); 
   }]);
```

If the above still doesn't solve the issue, try these things:

1. Manually startup angular, put the below code inside your on document ready

   `angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);`
2. Remove/ Update your jquery, sometime it's the jQuery that is incompatible/causing the problem in IE8

Hope this helps!